# Set the contents of a tag in HTML to the value of PHP 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a highscore table built into my website. Inside the  tags I have the following code:

```
function topScore() {
             $.get('topScore.php', function(data) {
               console.log(data); 
               alert(data); 
               });
}
```

The echo function for my PHP looks like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>$username</td><td>$wealth</td></tr>";
```

The tags mean it prints tags around each pair of inputs, so the total output looks a little something like this:

```
<tr><td>User1</td><td>2500</td></tr>
<tr><td>User2</td><td>1600</td></tr>
<tr><td>User3</td><td>1300</td></tr
<tr><td>User4</td><td>1000</td></tr>
```

etc...

This takes the echoed 'data' from topScore.php and logs it. So, how can I make it so that 'data' equals the contents of the  tags? If I can somehow do this, then the names will show up in the table. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I don't know if I'm overthinking it, but I'm really confused.

Edit: my code:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="620"><tbody>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Clicks</td>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <script>
function topScore() {
        $.get('topScore.php', function(data) {
        var html = $.parseHTML(data);

        $.each(html, function() {
        tds = $(this).find('td');
        user = tds[0].innerHTML;
        wealth = tds[1].innerHTML;

        $("#result").append("<p>" + user + " - " + wealth + "</p>");
        });
     });
}

          topScore()
          </script>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return the data as JSON from the PHP side, which makes it easier to parse. For example:

*topScore.php*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$data = ... // your array of [$username, $wealth] pairs

echo json_encode($data);
```

*javascript function*:

```
function topScore() {
     $.getJSON('topScore.php', function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        alert(data); 
     });
}
```

If you really want to parse the data as it is returned currently, there are several ways to do it. You could use regular expressions, but since it is HTML, you could take advantage of JQuery's built-in [parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) function. For example:

```
function topScore() {
     $.get('topScore.php', function(data) {
        var html = $.parseHTML(data);

        $.each(html, function() {
            console.log($(this).find('td').html());
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, the second solution just returns an 'undefined' error on Chrome for the $.each line.

Comment: My bad - I meant the "console.log($this)..." line

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested the solution and assumed the data is returned as above. See - https://jsfiddle.net/mepks58v/
You might need to modify this to fit your data (for example, if there are line breaks, you should remove them)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand... have a look at my code in the edited question above. Can you point what I did wrong? I don't get any results back in the console or anything like that. @AndreiSavin

Comment: any ideas? Reaally lost.

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing what the return from your data looks like. What do you get if you do console.log(data)?
My guess would be that the format is not exactly the same as in the fiddle.